Run oxygen tubing across a ceiling?
I want to run medical oxygen supply tubing across the ceiling of a bedroom.  (It currently lies on the floor, where it's a trip hazard and is prone to damage.)  The tubing is a light pliable plastic with an outer diameter of approximately 6.5 mm.
I designed and 3D-printed supports that could hold the tubing and could be attached to the ceiling with 3M Command-brand double-sided tapes.

Then I discovered that 3M Command tape rarely adheres to PLA or PETG.  So I need a different way to attach these supports to the ceiling.
Or, more generally, ...
How can I run oxygen tubing across a ceiling?

I'd like to be able to remove it without having to patch and paint the ceiling afterwards.
The ceiling is drywall, lightly textured (somewhere between "orange peel" and "knock down"), and painted with a very low sheen.
I'm reluctant to use brads, staples, or thumbtacks vertically into a drywall over a bed.
I don't want to fully enclose the tubing, as it needs to be replaced occasionally.



At each end, wrap the tubing around a large wire thimble using tape to keep it together, and hang the thimble on an open eye hook screwed into a wall stud. The tubing should be just slightly stretched. The tensile strength of the tubing is high compared to its weight, so this alone might be enough to hang it across the ceiling without sagging. You don't need to over-stretch it.


If the above alone is not enough, you can supplement it with fasteners.  I love these wire ties.  They are mountable, they include adhesive and also a screw hole, and it's great to use both.  They are white. They include the wire tie which can be opened and re-used.   Just stick and screw these to joists in  your ceiling as needed.




Or instead of the plastic fasteners use open eye hooks (see photo above) screwed into joists to prevent sagging.

To replace the tubing you just have to unhook everything and remove the tape that holds it to the eyelets.  Nothing needs to be unscrewed and everything gets reused except a piece of tape.

Up vote @ jay613. A tiny hole is much easier to repair than a quarter sized scar from sticking something on the ceiling.

A few ideas:

Redesign the 3D-printed part to include a screw hole, and screw into studs above the drywall.
Use coax cable pin-down clips, if you can find some with screws.
Get some wire chase like is used for surface-mount electrical cable and hide the hose in it.

(One benefit of the wire chase is the hose wont dip and sag across the ceiling like the 3D-parts or the coax cable clips would allow.)

Fairly small (thin, but say 1-3/4" long to go through drywall and 1" into studs) screws really won't make very big holes - not that much worse than picture-hanging holes. But very secure.

I appreciate the suggestions.  Screwing into studs (or, I guess, joists in this case) is a bit more permanent that I'm hoping for.  Screw-in coax clips would have to be unscrewed whenever we need to replace the tubing which can be as frequent as every three months.  I considered cable channel, but the self-adhesive ones I've used for other projects always failed--falling off the wall and taking the paint with it.  I wouldn't consider putting that on a ceiling.  But I see they also have versions that attach with screws, so I'll consider that.
